# Unwanted lost of the column names when applying manipulations on a list of data frames via lapply

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, lapply

I have a list of data frames corresponding to the sample below:

```
dta_a <- data.frame(geo=c(1:3), vals=c("1","3","#"))
dta_b <- data.frame(geo=c(1:3), vals=c("2","#","15"))
dta_c <- data.frame(geo=c(1:3), vals=c("2","11","15"))
lst <- list(dta_a, dta_b, dta_c)
```

The data frames are created in the course of importing files and I would like to apply some cleaning to each of the data frames. I am currently using the code below:

```
lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) {
  names(x) <- c("Geography",paste0("indicator_number_",as.character(x[1,2])))
  x <- x[-1,]
  x <- as.numeric(as.character(x[,2]))
})
```

It appears that the column names that were previously assigned to each of the data frames are now lost:

```
> names(lst[[1]])
NULL
```

However, interstingly applying the same function without the `x <- as.numeric(as.character(x[,2]))` appears to work:

```
> lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) {
+   names(x) <- c("Geography",paste0("indicator_number_",as.character(x[1,2])))
+   x <- x[-1,]
+   # x <- as.numeric(as.character(x[,2]))
+ })
> names(lst[[1]])
[1] "Geography"          "indicator_number_1"
```

I would like to know why it happens and how can I correctly subset elements of data frame inside the `lapply` function. The code `x <- x[-1,]` does what it should so I would expect that `x <- as.numeric(as.character(x[,2]))` will also work.

Comment: I think you need `x[,2] <- as.numeric(as.character(..` and `return(x)` i.e. `lst1 <- lapply(lst, function(x) {names(x) <- c("Geography",paste0("indicator_number_",as.character(x[1,2]))); x <- x[-1,]; x[,2] <- as.numeric(as.character(x[,2]));x})`

Comment: @akrun, thanks returning `x` works. I also made a mistake in my syntax it should be `x[,2]` when the column is being transformed.